# The total number of digits between two numbers

Tags: java

I am working on a program right now and part of it requires me to find the total amount of digits between two integers, I have figured it out for integers that have the same amount of digits, e.g. 1234 and 4980 (both have four digits) but I can't seem to figure it out for the integers that don't have the same amount of digits, i.e. 3 and 5698 (3 only has one digit and 5698 has four). How might I go about this?

Comment: I think the question is not really clear, what are "digits between two numbers"? Can you make an example?

Comment: What is the total number of digits between 1234 and 4980 then?

Comment: The total digits between 1234 and 4980 would be 14988

Comment: Can you explain your example?

Comment: Why 14988? How you calculated that number?

Comment: For example if the first number was 5 and second number was 10 and you were trying to find the total digits between them that would be 5,6,7,8,9,10 we know that 5,6,7,8,9 are single digits so we would add 1+1+1+1+1 and since 10 is a double digit we would add 2, so the sum of 1+1+1+1+1+2 would be the total number of digits between 5 and 10

Comment: I got 14988 because if you subtract 4980 by 1234 + 1 you get 3747, know that 1234 is a 4 digit number, by multiplying 4 by 3747 you get the total amount of digits between the two numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An straightforward way is to use logarithms.  The number of digits in an integer `n` is `(int)Math.log10(n)+1`.  Assuming you are doing inclusive computations on first thru last it would be as follows:

```
int sum = 0;
int first = 3;
int last = 3333;
for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    sum += Math.log10(i)+1;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
12223
```

But a more efficient and perhaps less obvious way it to forgo `logs` and simply compute in pieces. This will reduce number of iterations of the loop. This works by computing the number of digits and the power in increments. I put in print statements so you can see the progression.

```
int digits = 1;
int power = 10;
int limit = last;
sum = 0;
while(power < limit) {
    if (power > first) {
        sum += (power - first) * digits;
        System.out.println(power + " " + first  + " " + digits + " : partial running sum = " + sum);
        first = power;
    }
    
    digits++;
    power*= 10;
}
sum += (limit - power/10 + 1)*digits;
System.out.println(limit + " " + power/10  + " " + digits + " : partial running sum = " + sum);
System.out.println(sum);
```

prints

```
10 3 1 : partial running sum = 7
100 10 2 : partial running sum = 187
1000 100 3 : partial running sum = 2887
3333 1000 4 : final sum = 12223
12223
```

Comment: Your idea sounds great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Boy, the algorithm is *not* obvious – your last comment is rather crucial.

Evidently this question boils down to:

- For each 'number' between the 2, *including* **both** of the edges, count how many digits that number has.
- Sum those up.

For your example it's simply `(4980 - 1234 + 1) * 4` = 14988.

Sounds like you simply need to for-loop: `for (int i = 1234; i <= 4980; i++)`, and then for each `i` just figure out how many digits there are and add those.

Comment: Thank you so much! I completely forgot about for loops I will try this out!